# dspace installation issue on windows

Tags: installation, dspace

I was installing dspace on my PC. but I have face a failure when it downloads the package the failure starts at :

```
DSpace SOLR :: Local Customizations ................ FAILURE
```

and the other two have been skipped :

```
DSpace OAI-PMH :: Local Customizations ............. SKIPPED
DSpace Assembly and Configuration .................. SKIPPED
```

please help me

Here is what I shoot on my window screen :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X8xf.png]

Comment: Try running the mvn package from `C:\dspace-5.2-src-release` instead of `C:\dspace-5.2-src-release\dspace`.

Comment: thank you Bertrand-Martel i have passed this steep by trying many times. now the error is   " org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace" " when i enter this command "create-administrator"